# Procedure to color the edges of a circulant graph

Tags: co.combinatorics, graph-theory, algorithms, graph-colorings, cayley-graphs

From the first theorem in [this](https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/0095895685900565) paper, it is clear that a cayley graph on abelian group for all generating sets of even order is class $1$, that is can be edge colored in exactly $\Delta$ colors. But, this procedure and proof is not clear for me in the case of circulant graphs.

In the proof of the theorem $2.3$ of the above paper, the author proves the theorem for abelian groups by first proving the theorem for any graph defined on any generating set on the groups $H\rtimes G$. But, how can a graph defined on a cyclic group be written in this form?  Specifically, say we have a cyclic group of order $2p$, where $p$ is $\it{odd}$. Then, though the group is isomorphic to $\mathbb{Z}_p\times\mathbb{Z}_2$, i cannot see how a graph defined on the whole group $\mathbb{Z}_{2p}$ is isomorphic to a cartesian product of graphs of the form $\Gamma(S:\mathbb{Z}_p)\times\mathbb{Z}_2$, as expected from the paper. Am I missing something? Thanks beforehand.

Comment: The 14-cycle can be coloured with two colours, but there is no reason why it *must* be coloured with only two colours. Using more colours on the 14-cycle may leave you more flexibility in colouring the two 7-cycles in such a way that fewer colours are required overall.

Comment: @GordonRoyle thanks! so does this imply for a general algorithm we use all the colors on all the cycles (according to their lengths)?

Comment: Have you tried looking at the proof of the statement you claim, to see if it gives an algorithm?

Comment: @verret yes. it is the stong's paper. i quite dont get the algorithm, if any, described there. And surely, this is non-trivial, for an algorithm for any circulant graph seems not easy. And your downvote seems unjustified!

Comment: So the paper you already know about (which you should probably have explicitly included in your question) has the answer to your question. What you then asking?

Comment: @verret no, the paper shows that it is possible to 1-factorize the graph. But, the procedure is not clear. The paper is [here](https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/0095895685900565)

Comment: Right, and that proof can be turned into an algorithm. It's not very complicated, the whole proof with preliminaries is less than a page. So again, what is the question?

Comment: @verret edited the post. It is not clear to me how the proof holds for graphs on cyclic groups. Would be helpful if you could elaborate

Comment: Which specific part of the proof do you not see how it holds in this particular case?

Comment: @verret the part when the paper says that any graph for any gen. set on a group of the form $H\rtimes G$ can be edge colored using the edge coloring of the graph on $S\times \{s\}\quad s\in G\quad S\subset H$.